# Python Basic Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, procedure

I want to generate an ID number. If this random are same regenerate the random number.

```
import random
while True:
   def generateNumber(ID):
      value = random.randint(1, 2)
      if value != ID:
         return (value)
      generateNumber(value)
  a = int(input('Enter a data: '))
  print("->", generateNumber(a))
```

## Why this function return *None value* when the data are the same in recursion function?

I debug when the two data are equal, function recursion and call again itself and after generate value changed a different value. But this recursion still worked and return None type data.

Comment: In its current form, your problem is not reproducible; but apparently, with the necessary fixes, your question is a duplicate of a common beginner FAQ. Going forward, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

The function is returning `None` because there is a recursive call to a function called `generate()` instead of `generateNumber()`. Due to this typo, when the condition `if value != ID` is met, the function calls itself recursively with `generate(value)` instead of `generateNumber(value)`. Since the function `generate()` does not exist, it returns `None`, and ultimately the `generateNumber()` function also returns `None`.

To fix the issue, you should change the recursive call to `generateNumber(value)` so that the correct function is called. Here's the corrected code:

```
import random

def generateNumber(ID):
    value = random.randint(1, 2)
    if value != ID:
        return value
    return generateNumber(value)

a = int(input('Enter a data: '))
print("->", generateNumber(a))
```

Comment: sorry for my wrong question. If I use wrong function name, **NameError** will be raised. Thanks for your sharing